# storing ASCII on the blockchain

Tags: solidity, blockchain, arrays, storage, string

what is the best way to store ASCII characters/strings on the ethereum blockchain?
scenario:
there are users that want to upload ONLY ASCII strings to the blockchain.
these strings don't contain private info , so they can be stored as plaintext.
this is my implementation, is there a better solution?

```
contract storagex {
    mapping(address => string[]) public users;

    function add(string memory _data) public {
        users[msg.sender].push(_data);
    }

    function retrieve(address ad) public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return users[ad];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it, that's all you need. Solidity `string` is designed to hold ASCII printable characters only, from the range 0x20 to 0x7E, which would be in decimal from 32 to 126, which is from "Space" to "~".

Take a look at the docs:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/types.html#string-literals-and-types

ASCII table:

https://www.asciitable.com/